# Issue with WhiteSpace character in scanf's format

Tags: c, gcc, c++11, scanf

I use scanf to read the input from `stdin` since scanf is considered much faster than `cin`. I found the following unexpected behavior:

```
for(int i = 0; i<3; i++) {
    scanf("%d ", &t);
    printf("The input was %d\n", t);
}
```

The `"%d "` format in `scanf` is expected to read an integer and ignore the white-space or new-line characters after it. Hence the expected output should be something like:

```
0
The input was 0
1
The input was 1
2
The input was 2
```

However I get the follwing output:

```
0
1
The input was 0
2
The input was 1
```

Could someone please help me understand the behavior here?

Comment: `" %d"` instead of `"%d "`.

Comment: These sort of _typos_ should be documented in the `scanf` tag wiki.

Comment: If you use [`std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio), `std::cin` shouldn't perform worse than `std::scanf()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you type `1ENTER` the library code sees the `1` and matches it to `"%d"`. Then it sees the `ENTER` and starts matching that to `" "`. As nothing else gets in, it waits and waits and waits.

After a while you type `2ENTER`. Since `scanf()` is still waiting for whitespace and `2` is not whitespace the call terminates successfuly, leaving the `2` in the buffer and printing `"The input was 1"`.

and so on ...

So, do not put spaces at the end of the conversion specification -- or anywhere else since most conversion specification **already** do leading whitespace suppresion.

Answer (score 1):

Put the space *before* the `%d`. Or, even better, remove it!

Also, check the return value of `scanf()` before relying on `t` having a valid value.